# Unit Testing MonoDroid

Tags: unit-testing, xamarin.android

How does one go about writing unit tests for Mono for Android? I can't use my normal unit tests because of bugs/missing methods in the MonoDroid framework.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you can't use your normal test runner against Mono for Android libraries since they target different profiles, and isn't specific to Mono for Android itself. [Andr.Unit](https://github.com/spouliot/Andr.Unit) is a project that provides a basic NUnitLite test runner so that you can run NUnit tests right in the emulator or on a device.

An approach I usually try to take is to keep as much logic as possible in class libraries that are independent of any particular platform or UI. Then I can link those files into a standard class library and run unit tests against those with any runner/framework.